# How to display Product Customizable Options without tax?

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-calculation

I have a Magento `2.4.3` store.

By default I want product's price and `Customizable Options` to be displayed **without** tax.

Product's price is displayed correctly, **without** tax.

`Customizable Options` however are displayed **including** tax. How do I display `Customizable Options` **without** tax?

Here is how `Customizable Options` look like in the admin panel:
[image]

This is how the `Customizable Options` are displayed now:
[image]

And this is how I want them to be displayed:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: did  you find a solution to this one? could you share it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured this one out and posting in case I forget in future, but also to assist with anyone else who was looking for a solution to this problem :)
So I basically resolved this using a custom totals collector, as follows:

#### Step 1

Create `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/sales.xml` file and reference a new collector class as follows for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="tax_subtotal" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Subtotal" sort_order="600"/>
        </group>
    </section>
</config>
```

#### Step 2

Create your custom class PHP file `app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Subtotal.php` with something like the following:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Sales\Total\Quote;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory as CustomerAddressFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory as CustomerAddressRegionFactory;
use Magento\Tax\Helper\Data as TaxHelper;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax;
use Magento\Tax\Model\Config;
use Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassKeyInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class Subtotal extends Tax
{
    public function __construct(
        Config $taxConfig,
        TaxCalculationInterface $taxCalculationService,
        QuoteDetailsInterfaceFactory $quoteDetailsDataObjectFactory,
        QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory $quoteDetailsItemDataObjectFactory,
        TaxClassKeyInterfaceFactory $taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory,
        CustomerAddressFactory $customerAddressFactory,
        CustomerAddressRegionFactory $customerAddressRegionFactory,
        TaxHelper $taxData,
        Json $serializer
    ) {

        parent::__construct(
            $taxConfig,
            $taxCalculationService,
            $quoteDetailsDataObjectFactory,
            $quoteDetailsItemDataObjectFactory,
            $taxClassKeyDataObjectFactory,
            $customerAddressFactory,
            $customerAddressRegionFactory,
            $taxData,
            $serializer
        );
    }

    /**
     * Calculate tax on product items. The result will be used to determine shipping
     * and discount later.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return $this
     */
    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        // return if no items in quote
        if (!$quote->getItems()) {
            return $this;
        }

        // set some default values
        $subtotal = 0;
        $tax = 0;
        $quoteId = $quote->getId();

        foreach ($quote->getItems() as $quoteItem) {
            $productId = $quoteItem->getProductId();

            // if current item requires VAT relief
              // update row totals for item (remove VAT)
              $this->setRowExclTax($quoteItem);
                
              // add to cart subtotal
              $subtotal += $quoteItem->getBaseRowTotalInclTax();

              // add to cart tax
              $tax += $quoteItem->getBaseTaxAmount();
        }

        // Update the cart totals for subtotal, total Inc/Ex tax etc 
        $this->updateCartTotals($total, $subtotal, $tax);      

        return $this;
    }

   // Sets the item row calculations and removes Tax
    private function setRowExclTax($quoteItem) 
    {
        // calculate the subtotal for each item row
        $rowTotal = ($quoteItem->getPrice() * $quoteItem->getQty());

        // Calculate item row totals
        $quoteItem->setPrice($quoteItem->getPrice());
        $quoteItem->setBasePrice($quoteItem->getBasePrice());
        $quoteItem->setPriceInclTax($quoteItem->getPrice());
        $quoteItem->setBasePriceInclTax($quoteItem->getBasePrice());
        $quoteItem->setRowTotal($rowTotal);
        $quoteItem->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal);
        $quoteItem->setRowTotalInclTax($rowTotal);
        $quoteItem->setBaseRowTotalInclTax($rowTotal);

        // Remove Tax
        $quoteItem->setTaxAmount(0);
        $quoteItem->setBaseTaxAmount(0);
        $quoteItem->setTaxPercent(0);
    }

    // updates totals such as subtotal, price Incl/Excl Tax etc. 
    private function updateCartTotals($total, $subtotal, $tax)
    {
        $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', $subtotal);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', $subtotal);
        $total->setSubtotalInclTax($subtotal);
        $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($subtotal);

        // Remove Tax 
        $total->setTotalAmount('tax', $tax);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', $tax);

        // Set the grand total Inc Tax total
        $total->setGrandTotal($subtotal);
    }
}
```

And that was pretty much it :)
everything now works as planned when removing VAT from specific items. Hopefully this will help someone else when they need it.

You can see

Comment: thank you but this is not what i need. i want the price to be displayed for each option but have it without tax

Comment: Please check now.